# How to pass environment variables to Apache Superset docker container on Azure Container Instances

Tags: docker, environment-variables, azure-cli, apache-superset, azure-container-instances

I'm able to create a working container group of Apache Superset using the Azure CLI like this:

```
az container create --resource-group myrg --name superset-test --image apache/superset:1.5.1 --dns-name-label superset-test --ports 80 8088 --cpu 2 --memory 8
```

Now I want to pass some environment vars to customize the deployment, e.g., I want the database backend to be my Azure Postgres Flexible Server, not the default Postgres docker container `superset_db`.  But I can't figure out how to pass that info via environment variables.

I've tried like this, with `--environment-variables`:

```
az container create --resource-group myrg --name superset-test --image apache/superset:1.5.1
 --dns-name-label superset-test --ports 80 8088 --cpu 2 --memory 8 --environment-variables DATABASE_DIALECT="postgresql"
"DATABASE_USER"="superset" "DATABASE_PASSWORD"="superset" "DATABASE_HOST"="azpostgresql1.mydomain.com"
"DATABASE_PORT"="5432" "DATABASE_DB"="superset"
```

But they seem to be ignored - the Superset container starts up the same way and no data is populated into my db.  Can I do this via the CLI?  Or is there another way I should execute this deployment?

**Update**: I'm now focused on the *SECRET_KEY* variable since, if one is not passed, the default is used and a message appears in the container once I connect to it via the Azure web portal and run `superset init`:

> A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.

That's a clean way to verify that the problem is in my env variables.  Once the container starts up, I can verify the connection to the same Postgres DB I want to use as the application backend by listing it as a database source and testing the connection.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the variables using "az container show": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables#verify-environment-variables ?

Comment: `az container show ...` returns `"containers[].environmentVariables"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this container via the Azure web portal as per [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables#azure-portal-example)? This would ensure all variables are present and parsed correctly.

Azure documentation suggests using single quotes `'` rather than double `"` for env var specification. As per this [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables#azure-cli-example). Though I realise it shouldn't really make much difference.

If you won't have any luck with the above, you may want to explore another option - have you seen the Superset [database connection UI](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/db-connection-ui/)? It may prove useful in checking the connectivity.

Other than that, it's difficult to explore other options. A bit more context would help:

- have you seen any traffic arrive at the target database?
- is there any traffic in the local Postgres instead?
- any chance you can confirm in the web portal that the variables were set correctly via the cli?

Comment: Good ideas, I've updated the post as I've narrowed it down a little.  I have tried running it through the Azure web portal as a new Azure Container Instance many times, no luck, even with the simple `SECRET_KEY` var that I can verify didn't work based on a warning.  And now I know it's not an issue with how the Postgres db is networked, thanks to the database connection UI.

But I'm still stuck on how else to debug + what else to try.

Comment: so just to be 100% sure, when you log into the container via the web portal, can you run `echo $SECRET_KEY` just to confirm the variable is not there? if the variable pops up, then we know it's to do with superset, if it doesn't pop up, then it's to do with the azure.

Comment: Indeed the variable does pop up when I do that!  But then when I run the first init command `superset fab create-admin` immediately after the `echo`, I get the `WARNING: A Default SECRET_KEY was detected`.

Comment: Ok, I went through the Superset config implementation and they're not reading the SECRET_KEY from env var at all, only the Database and Redis variables. Fortunately, though, this only produces a warning. Let's revert to trying the DATABASE_* variables, ok? Can you check what are the logs saying? The app tries to apply migrations at the beginning so there should be an error in the logs if it can't do it and psycopg would give a reason.

Comment: I tried supplying those `DATABASE_` variables as well as the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and while all can be verified with `echo` as having been supplied correctly, none are taking.  I don't see errors in the logs related to a database because Superset is defaulting to creating a SQLite database at `~/.superset_home/superset.db'.

Comment: This is still an unresolved question and I'd love to know what the problem is.  But you looking into it affirms that I'm not missing something obvious.  With this problem persisting, and with separate problems I'm having getting `docker compose` to deploy to Azure Container Instances, I'm going to explore options other than ACI for using Superset in the cloud.  I'll award the bounty to this answer - thank you - but leave the question open in case an answer eventually describes how to get this use case working.

Comment: Thank you. I'll carry on trying to help, but im drawn closer and closer to recommending you use custom config file rather than env vars. What you said is interesting, can you find the `superset_config.py` file within the container and check if it's even reading the env vars? The default one appears to be reading env vars (both in v1.5 and v2), but maybe yours is different for some reason.

Comment: @trust512 and anyone who may find this useful. I've had a superset start-up issue in Docker on my local and came to your post here as I'm receiving the "Default SECRET_KEY" issue sighted in your post. It turns out (from looking at config.py) that the Secret Key's environment name is SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY (rather than SECRET_KEY) and passing a custom key on Docker run / up resolves this error. Hopefully this will help anyone facing similar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **CLI** use **PgAdmin**. In PgAdmin, we can connect our application to Postgres to local or on azure platform. The environment variables which were shown in the question, directly mentioned in the PgAdmin credentials and it will allow access to the application to database.

Follow the steps:

- Open **PgAdmin**
- On the **Left** click on **Servers**
- Click on **Dropdown**
- Right Click on **Open Clusters** and select properties
- Click on **Open Connection** tab and give all the environment variables which were created.
- Check the working of the application again after setting up all the variables.